# Upgraded application to Spring 4.3.7 and JDK 8. After this Spring beans are not loading. Beanfactory factory itself is NULL

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I have the following error, could someone help me? Thank you in advance for your help.

```
11/24/17 4:21:43:949 EST] 000000a2 ContextLoader I
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization
completed in 15836 ms
    [11/24/17 4:21:43:949 EST] 000000a2 SystemOut O TRIMS.properties file getting loaded on path:
/opt/applications/trims_main_ASIA/SIT1/config/TRIMSConfig.properties
    [11/24/17 4:21:44:021 EST] 000000a2 SystemOut O MenuServletContextListener:: Menu XML config loaded.
    [11/24/17 4:21:44:147 EST] 000000a2 webapp E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated
SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.citigroup.trims.framework.cache.Cache.loadStaticCache(Cache.java:112)
    at com.citigroup.trims.framework.cache.Cache.init(Cache.java:83)
    at com.citigroup.trims.framework.cache.CacheManager.initialize(CacheManager.java:112)
    at com.citigroup.trims.framework.cache.CacheStartup.contextInitialized(CacheStartup.java:30)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1732)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:415)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201
```

I really appreciate!

Comment: You can't expect a solution of your problem by posting the **ERROR** only!

Comment: I edited a bit, but yeah could we have some explanation? Thank you!